# In Facet API, if I select a item from one category then the count of items in other category will become zero. What can i do for this?

Tags: performance, search

I'm working with [facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi), if I have select a item from one category then the count of items in other category will become zero. What can I do for this ?

this is before i select a item in a category

[image: snap1]

this is after i select a item in a category(i.e in this picture when i select a item in 'Filter By Location' the count of items in 'Filter by service category' becomes 0
[image: snap2]

[image: this is when i select item from both categories,it doest disply any products even if there are items]

Comment: Please confirm while selecting "Udupi" any service category is selected in same content.

Comment: no it doesn't work..

Comment: i have made changes but doesn't work..please anyone help me with proper solution

Comment: have you check there configuration setting ?